# SwiftUI: List data dissapears after you dismiss sheet

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui, reload

I have a list of horizontal images. And a little profile/settings button in the navigation bar. When you click the profile button, a sheet view slides up, and when you dismiss it, the list seems to lose it's cells (HStacks of other images basically)

Here's the code that displays the sheet and list

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<self.categories.count) {
                    ExploreRow(title: self.categories[$0])
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Justview")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: profileButton)
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingProfile) {
                Text("User Profile: \(self.userData.userProfile.username)")
            }
        }
    }
```

`ExploreRow` is essentially a horizontal stack in a scroll view that displays images loaded from the web.

Before Sheet image:

[image]

After Sheet dismiss image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there are not many `categories` in the `List` (as they should not be many), so the simplest is just force-rebuild list (supposing you don't make anything heavy in `ExploreRow.init`, like

```
List {
    ForEach(0..<self.categories.count) {
        ExploreRow(title: self.categories[$0])
    }.id(UUID())
}
.navigationBarTitle("Justview")
```

*The issue is due to List's caching-reusing row views, it is known.

Comment: Hi! There're 4 categories for now. And each row has 10 items. I tried adding the `.id` modifier but it results in the whole list disappearing. Is there a way to make the list cache everything (i.e. the row and the views in the row)?

Comment: I cannot test, becase don't have your code but try different places for id.