# SwiftUI Introspect library pull to refresh issue

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview, uirefreshcontrol

I want to implement pull to refresh in my scrollview in SwiftUi. So I have been trying [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library to use its `.introspectScrollView` and use refresh controller.
But I have been getting an issue with it, the refresh progress spinner immediately gets hidden in my end. So I wanted to know how to keep showing the refresh spinner until the data loads.

Also please note I am not using list as I have subViews inside the ScrollView, so I am still using ScrollView.

My code is -

```
   ScrollView{
     //subView1
     //subView2
   }.introspectScrollView { scrollView in
           let control = UIRefreshControl()
           control.addTarget(viewModel, action: #selector(viewModel.loadData1), for: .valueChanged)
           scrollView.refreshControl = control
           viewModel.isRefreshed = {
                control.endRefreshing()
           }
     }


   //In view model 
   var isRefreshed: (() -> ())?
   func loadData1(){
      // load data 1
      loadData2()
    }
   func loadData2(){
      //load data2
       
      isRefreshed?()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. And the negative vote is not mine. Like I suggested in the other question, if you use `List` instead of `UIScrollView`, you can use the `refreshable` modifier.

Comment: Let me check if I can use List instead of UIScrollView as there is difference in visual in both the two

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/refreshable(action:)

Comment: @loremipsum This is for list in SwiftUi but not for ScrollView.

Comment: @koen As I said in the question, I have multiple subviews.

Comment: @koen oh sorry, i thought i had did it earlier

Comment: So maybe [edit] your question and better explain what you are trying to accomplish, a picture could be useful. And you can have a List with different subviews.

Comment: @koen Yes I have edited it now

Comment: @Manas Here's a refreshable `List` with subviews: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-enable-pull-to-refresh

Comment: @koen Sorry to say this is not subview. this is a list of texts. List basically supports and looks well for list of items, for example - a list of students of a class or list of states of countries. But for subview in scrollview I mean like a collection of different types of views for example - home page of app like Spotify or home page of an ecommerce app

Comment: @Manas `Text` *is* a `View`, so you can just replace it with your own views.

Comment: @Manas - some friendly advice. If an answer has been upvoted 3 times or more it is definitely worth trying out. If it works and you don't like importing the package, figure out what is being called and integrate it into your own app.

Comment: @koen yes text is a view which can be used in list. But list is not applicable to my complex view which has horizontal scrollviews and other complex view. List views design if different from scrollView. You can read the two difference that I already pointed out of using list view and ScrollView. `List` views is useful to display a list of text or such similar simple views like list of students or a list of states or countries. But to design a home pages app like food delivery app or an ecommerce app or a streaming app, you can't use the list view which is has some limilation in its appearance.

Comment: @Mozahler, yes I have already seen that library `SwiftUIRefresh` before that answer and I would never use such a library which is not updated in last two years. Also the library is not for `ScrollView` which is my point of interest, rather it is for `List` view in SwiftUi. So the answer is not only respecting my question's context but is also not relevant. So I believe the answer doesn't deserve any upvotes rather downvotes

Comment: @Mozahler, i can easily find such answer in stackoverflow or even has visited the SwiftUIRefresh earlier before it. The answer provided is totally a copy of other answer and is a general solution of list pull to refresh and not related to this question

Comment: OK. Take a look at  var isRefreshed: (() -> ())? -- make sure your logic in the view model matches your expectations, you haven't provided any of the triggering logic (although it is hinted at in loadData1() and loadData2()

Comment: @Mozahler No the logic is right as I have used it with UIKit ScrollView and it works fine, but using UIKit i have an strange issue which i posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304432/using-uiscrollview-correctly-in-swiftui). But since i couldn't get it solved so I tried to alternatively use this approach in the question

Comment: How about putting a scrollview as the only subview of List? Then you can make all your fancy subviews inside the scrollview, and have the pull to refresh functionality with the List.

Comment: @koen will it be good practice to have two such view, one nested under another

Comment: You will have to try that out yourself to see if this works.

Comment: @koen I tried ScrollView inside List but there is an issue of - List's caching-reusing row views which hides the data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60776352/13674724) with solution. But the solution increases CPU usage , earlier my app CPU usage on loading the view was 34% but now it rises upto 75%

Answer (score 3):

You could try the SwiftUIRefresh package, that includes both Introspect and SwiftuiRefresh packages. So, add `https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUIRefresh.git` link to your package and use this like

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIRefresh

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowing = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Item 1")
            Text("Item 2")
        }
        .pullToRefresh(isShowing: $isShowing) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.isShowing = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source code from: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUIRefresh

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use this library as of now, I am using a different library now

Comment: @Manas you don’t have to use that library, you can look at how it works and use that knowledge to fix your problem.

Comment: This is for list not for scrollview